# Ghidra pseudocode to Java/C

Tags: c, decryption, java, ghidra

I have this piece of code generated from Ghidra

```
void __cdecl FUNCTION(uint *key,uint *text)

{
  undefined uVar1;
  ushort uVar2;
  uint *puVar3;
  uint *puVar4;
  uint *puVar5;
  int iVar6;
  uint uVar7;
  uint *puVar8;
  uint uVar9;
  uint local_18c [11];
  uint *local_14;
  uint *local_10;
  uint local_c;

  puVar3 = key;
  uVar2 = 0;
  local_10 = (uint *)key[4];
  local_14 = (uint *)key[3];
  puVar5 = local_18c;
  uVar9 = key[1];
  puVar8 = (uint *)key[2];
  uVar7 = *key;
  do {
    local_c = uVar7;
    key = puVar8;
    puVar4 = local_14;
    if (uVar2 < 0x10) {
      puVar5[0xe] = *text;
      uVar1 = *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x3b);
      *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x3b) = *(undefined *)(puVar5 + 0xe);
      *(undefined *)(puVar5 + 0xe) = uVar1;
      uVar1 = *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x3a);
      *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x3a) = *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x39);
      *(undefined *)((int)puVar5 + 0x39) = uVar1;
    }
    else {
      uVar7 = puVar5[0xb] ^ puVar5[6] ^ puVar5[-2] ^ *puVar5;
      puVar5[0xe] = uVar7 >> 0x1f | uVar7 * 2;
    }
    if (uVar2 < 0x14) {
      iVar6 = (~uVar9 & (uint)local_14 | (uint)key & uVar9) + 0x5a827999;
    }
    else {
      if (uVar2 < 0x28) {
        iVar6 = ((uint)local_14 ^ (uint)key ^ uVar9) + 0x6ed9eba1;
      }
      else {
        if (uVar2 < 0x3c) {
          iVar6 = (((uint)key | uVar9) & (uint)local_14 | (uint)key & uVar9) + 0x8f1bbcdc;
        }
        else {
          iVar6 = ((uint)local_14 ^ (uint)key ^ uVar9) + 0xca62c1d6;
        }
      }
    }
    text = text + 1;
    puVar8 = puVar5 + 0xe;
    puVar5 = puVar5 + 1;
    uVar7 = (int)local_10 + iVar6 + (local_c >> 0x1b | local_c << 5) + *puVar8;
    puVar8 = (uint *)(uVar9 << 0x1e | uVar9 >> 2);
    uVar2 = uVar2 + 1;
    local_10 = local_14;
    local_14 = key;
    uVar9 = local_c;
  } while (uVar2 < 0x50);
  *puVar3 = *puVar3 + uVar7;
  puVar3[1] = puVar3[1] + local_c;
  puVar3[2] = puVar3[2] + (int)puVar8;
  puVar3[3] = puVar3[3] + (int)key;
  puVar3[4] = puVar3[4] + (int)puVar4;
  return;
}
```

I'm trying to translate it in Java or C code, but i don't understand how. there are some obscure points.

All variable are typed correctly, but the first uVar1 is "undefined", why?

The operator ~ how is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ghidra help:

> By default, the variables data type will be UndefinedN where N is the size (in bytes) of the stack reference.

`undefined` stands for `undefined1` and it's a type of size `1`(byte) in `Ghidra`.

If some variable is of this type, it basically means that decompiler didn't infer any "better" type for this variable (which could be `bool` or `char` for example), but it knows that it occupies `1` byte.

Regarding your second question, `~` is a `bitwise NOT` operation, just like in `C`.

**Note1:** If you are unsure what a particular operator means, just select it in decompiler view and it will show you the corresponding disassembly instruction.

**Note2:** The code you are analysing may be easier to read when you disable printing of type casts (`Edit`->`Tool options...`->`Decompiler`->`Display`->`Disable printing of type casts`).

**Note3:** Another option to consider is `Use inplace assignment operations` (under `Decompiler`->`Analysis` in options) to have `uVar2 += 1` instead of `uVar2 = uVar2 + 1` for example.